# picture goes off screen on a smaller resolution?

Tags: html, css

very very new to coding but I'm mostly familiar with C and i ran into a problem while trying to set up my website, I have a computer and a laptop. my site looks just fine on my computer but when i swap to my laptop i notice my border/header goes off screen. as you can see in the code I've tried just about anything wrapping, taking away padding...! I want it to fit the screen and not go off screen for all resolutions (exluding on phones)

Sorry again if this isnt structured very well I'm very new to all of this but I'm having alot of fun!

Code:
CSS

```
   #maincontainer2
                {
                 position:relative;
                 box-sizing: border-box;
                 background-repeat:no-repeat;
                 height: 100%;
                 width: 100%;
                 left:0;top:0;
                 max-width: 100%
                 max-height: 100%;
                 float:middle
                }
       body 
                {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: table;
                margin: auto;
                box-sizing: border-box
                margin: 0;
                }
HTML
<div id="maincontainer2" class="container-fluid">
</div>

<img src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/794994238038605904/998116976310353930/the_bg.png" 
object-fit: contain; position: absolute; float:absolute; box-sizing: border-box; 
width:100%; height:100%; height: auto; max-width: 100%; left:0; right:0; >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have so many wrong stuff:

- there is no `float: middle/absolute`
- you are missing `style` attribute in `img`, but also you can use in CSS instead
- you are missing `;` in some places
- you are duplicating properties such as `height`

Here is a minimalist version of your code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer2" class="container-fluid">
  <img class="image" src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/794994238038605904/998116976310353930/the_bg.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind awnser! :-D I'm sorry my code was so messy! though this does mess up some of the other images i have on my page i will be virtuous and try to fix the individual little images!

Comment: use class instead of img I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use Picture element for landscape and portrait devices with different width

```
<picture>
<source
    media="(orientation: landscape)"
    srcset="image-small.png 320w,
            image-medium.png 800w,
            image-large.png 1200w"
    sizes="(min-width: 60rem) 80vw,
           (min-width: 40rem) 90vw,
           100vw">
<source
    media="(orientation: portrait)"
    srcset="image-small-portrait.png 160w,
            image-medium-portrait.png 400w,
            image-large-portrait.png 600w"
    sizes="(min-width: 60rem) 80vw,
           (min-width: 40rem) 90vw,
           100vw">
<img src="image-small.png" alt="Image description">
```

or you can use img tag with srcset

```
<img src="image-small.png"
    srcset="image-small.png 320w, image-medium.png 800w, image-large.png 1200w"
    sizes="(min-width: 60rem) 80vw,
           (min-width: 40rem) 90vw,
           100vw"
    alt="Image description">
```

one more thing, for image lazy loading

```
<img src="very_and_expensive_img_to_load" decoding="async" />
```

The decoding="async" attribute will tell the browser that it is OK for image decoding to be done at a later moment so that the browser can continue displaying content even if the images are not fully loaded.